# Are dimensions of physical quantities and 1D/2D/3D/4D... spacetime dimensions the same?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, spacetime-dimensions, si-units

Are the [L]/[M]/[T]... dimensions of length/mass/time... somehow related to
1/2/3/4D spacetime dimensions?
If not; why are they called dimensions and what do they actually mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they have nothing to do with one another.  As per the Wiki article on [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#History), Poisson first used the word "dimension" to refer to physical units in 1833.